# Firebase 3 Auth + Node + jsonwebtoken: Invalid custom token

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, firebase-authentication

I have my own OAuth 2 server running on Node.js v4.4.5, with all this stuff:

```
"bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
"body-parser": "^1.15.1",
"cors": "^2.7.1",
"express": "~4.1.1",
"firebase": "^3.0.3",
"mongoose": "^4.4.19",
"oauth2orize": "^1.3.0",
"passport": "^0.3.2",
"passport-jwt": "^2.0.0",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0"
"jsonwebtoken": "^7.0.0"
```

I can login and get a JWT that, according to jwt.io, can be decoded, but I can't verify since I don't have the public key.

I get the JWT and send it to signInWithCustomToken and then I get an error from https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyCustomToken?key=AIzaSy....

```
{
        "error": {
        "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "invalid",
            "message": "INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN"
        }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN"
    }
}
```

In my **auth.js** controller, I have create the JWT like so:

```
var token = jwt.sign(
    {
        iss: jwt_config.client_email,
        sub: jwt_config.client_email,
        aud: 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit',
        iat: iat,
        exp: exp,
        uid: user._id,
        claims: {
            username: user.username, 
            user_id: user._id, 
            roles: user.role
        }
    },
    jwt_config.private_key, 
    {
        algorithm: 'RS256'
    }
);
res.json({success: true, token: token});
```

I load the service account data into jwt_config:

```
var jwt_config = require('../config/Firebase-68824d8xxxxx.json');
```

This is the offending JWT:

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.gDghMzXc2sFP4XbMhrU2kxo7u0yte4PT03AbeyzT8oGLYJEHJOAY-kZT0l_fGWDi68AfVCaEiHeFj1a3-M95i4NRTQErWyGPuqqS9ii2m0mDaBseFZumk5iTTWiqY8Tpo6_7fkWGsuM7fnuXjaMKV8jkOWS913EE3DQmXHT5bwPe-ky-xTFxU0P3VPWzbgw5T5lExmzpv0x78Fr-RCy45QhfJ3IeVa-Pyhnp4_NY9VAi1naJLpwKKo7aVq3uLujMK8ViNSgfdXTqI9VNq7KrdgqSKnpdoZ2ph_J6fHBnHtAhV6F_Iy_FyC7Zg1EyC_4vMpBJuMx5UYzy6f1Gm0wvHw

When I recieve it back at mi login page, I send it to Firebase:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'http://ec2-52...compute.amazonaws.com:3000/api/authenticate',
    data: $('#loginForm').serialize(),
    complete: function(result) {
        result = result.responseJSON;
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
        var success = result.success;
        if (success) {
            var data = result.token;

            firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(data).catch(function(error) {
                // Handle Errors here.
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var data = error.message;
                // ...
            });

        } else {
            var data = result.message;
        }
        $('#token').html(data);
    }
});
```

And here is where the error pops up.

I'm stumped, what should I do?

should I look into a different module to create the JWT?

Is there some way to know what is specifically wrong about the JWT?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I did it!
Turns out that in my claims, username and user_id were objects!
So, by doing this:

```
claims: {
    username: String(user.username), 
    user_id: Strint(user._id), 
    roles: user.role
}
```

it works!

Hope someone finds this helpful.

Comment: Judging by the... basically a million... questions there are about the Firebase 3 auth system, it's safe to say that either their API responses and/or their docs are insufficient.  Some of the answers from the authors and maintainers are passive-aggressively helpful at best, and flat out useless at other times.  Thanks for posting the solution upon solving this problem!

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation, the token created on the server side had been created with an expiration of 2 hours. There was no error when creating the token, only when trying to use it on the client side. Changing the expiration to one hour fixed the "Invalid Custom Token" problem.